# Excel - Remove the first nth Dashes from a column and leave the last

Tags: excel

I have data in a column like this. I need to remove all the dashes with the exception of the last, right dash.

So data in the column like this:

```
QQQ-NE
Q-A-123-N
Q-B-234-BE
Q-BB-999-RW
```

To this

```
 QQQ-NE
 QA123-N
 QB234-BE
 QBB999-RW
```

I assume I use **SUBSTITUTE()**. But how I can just leave the last dash?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: Excel 2010 and higher

Comment: Can you define "and higher"? It makes quite a difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably can be simplified, but some nested SUBSTITUTEs works:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))),"-",""),"~","-")
```

[image]